# JMETER __P cannot digest the value

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I  have a variable that I use in my API's header.
It contains many special characters in that string so JMeter cannot digest the value.
'myCode' variable I plan to use in CLI (NON-GUI) mode so I need to be able to control it.
Sometimes I see also double or single quotes ('"' and "'")in the string so it can be a case that I need to deal with this
Any ideas on how to handle this?

```
${__P(myCode,0$M@3C3dKLo&1=9gIYP#CvC5.sWNvDD2mTWmn)=uoj}peA6W8?ry]s/Tn}J{C:Z%,J?M0+{&&ywi]3wM"1lG(&!q++88b1B>I2G1=+cso}trWmOSIo]INi^&%&^GYUFFsgdnJ.TsPTM[Jq+g2CWKvRZ495G0DqH>Yj%sUPqhj2aCmbWun)}
```

Answer (score 0):

JMeter can "digest" the value, if you're trying to override the property via [`-J` command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override) - refer to your shell documentation as some characters might need [escaping](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/special-characters-in-shell-scripts).

Another option is defining your property in [*user.properties* file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization) or in a completely separate file and using [__FileToString() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) to read it